# how to select variables in same cells of multiple workbooks in Excel

Tags: excel, loops, copy, export

I am running an experiment that is 8 weeks long and consists of about 100 subjects.  There are variables from each week that I would like to select, but each subject has his own workbook.  Is there a way to select the variables (which are the same cells in each workbook) all into one workbook?  or can I do this with macro?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull values from a cell in another workbook with a formula like this (assuming the other workbook is in the same folder):

```
=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1
```

Or you can specify the full path to another workbook like this (note where the single quotes go -- particularly the one after the sheet name):

```
='C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\test\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

I think Excel automatically changes it to the full path style when you put it in the first way I mentioned.  You can of course use the value in equations as well:

```
=6 + 5 * [Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1
```

Comment: what if the cells are not identical in each workbook, how do I navigate around that problem?

Comment: @Jared I'm not entirely sure what you're asking...  Could you elaborate more?  Are you just saying that the numbers are different between the subjects' workbooks?  Are you saying that values you're trying to pull in are different types (string, number, date, etc.)?  Are you saying that you're trying to pull in cells/ranges from different locations in different workbooks?  In particular, what do you mean by "the cells are not identical in each workbook"?